# Installing Joomla on Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, joomla

I am trying to locally install joomla on my laptop. I have apache2 installed and working. When I go to localhost:8080 I get to the Joomla's install page. This is what I see

```
PHP Version >= 4.3.10   Yes   
- Zlib Compression Support  Yes   
- XML Support   Yes   
- MySQL Support     No   
MB Language is Default  Yes   
MB String Overload Off  Yes   
configuration.php Writable  No
```

So.. some basic questions. How do I enable MySQL support? I have MySQL 5.1.49 installed on the machine already and I am using it with a rails set up so it is installed and working. It may have something to do with mod_sql, but I can't find any info regarding that online.

My other question is how do I make configuration.php writeable?

Comment: Got the configuration.php working by making an empty file in the joomla directory called "configuration.php" and setting it so that it could be read and written.

Comment: There should be a configuration.php, I can't remember, its been a while since my initial setup, but I am sure there is one provided, it might need to be renamed, read the install manual to find it

Comment: You REALLY want to be sure that the permissions on configuration.php is owned and permissioned correctly. Owned by www-data and only it can read-write. Otherwise everyone will have the connection information to your MySQL server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much better than installing MySQL on its own, use the specialized package installer TaskSel. This acts like apt, but installs and configures for specific tasks. Run `sudo tasksel install lamp-server`.  Edit: you may also check that you have 'libapache2-mod-php5' installed.

As to permissions, if you have the directory /var/www/joomla then `cd /var/www` and then `sudo chown -R www-data joomla/`. This is how you allow the files to be owned by the web server and not root. Should fix it.

Comment: I have libapache2-mod-php5 installed. Is there anyway to do it without installing lamp-server?

Comment: From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP I see that the task is basically: apache2 php5-mysql libapache2-mod-php5 mysql-server do you have all of these?

Comment: May be obvious: have you restared apache? `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Cool, enjoy! Joomla is a lot of fun.